# php - How to unset array element in this condition

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, unset

My array looks like this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [value] => Array (
            [source] => vimeo
            [url] => https://vimeo.com/000000
        ) 
        [type] => videos 
    )
    [2] => Array ( 
        [value] => 62 
        [type] => images 
    ) 
)
```

I want to unset the array **id** with the **type => images**.

I tried this:

```
$key = array_search('images',$slides); 
unset($slides[$key]);
```

and it only deletes the first item in the array!!!

**Update:**

After all, I did it this way:

```
foreach ( $slides as $slide => $value) {
    if ($display_mode == 'images' &&  $value['type'] == 'videos') {
        unset($slides[$slide]);
    } elseif ($display_mode == 'videos' &&  $value['type'] == 'images') {
        unset($slides[$slide]); 
    }  
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($slides as $key => $slide) {
    if (in_array('images', $slide)) unset($slides[$key]);
}
```

Comment: eBrian -- you'd need to use a reference to $slide for that to work.  Otherwise the changes will be abandoned after each iteration.  Otherwise, a foreach is perfectly feasible =)

Comment: @KevinNielsen, not true. Note that I am unsetting in the array directly and not attempting to unset $slide. Ultimately what this does is unset($slides[2]).

Answer (score 2):

`array_search` returns false if `$needle` is not found. `false` casts to `0` when used as an integer. You might want to consider [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) for your use case:

```
$array = array(...);

$array = array_filter($array, function($item) { return in_array('images', $item); });
```